# Scaling a Dijkstra's Algorithm implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-theory

I have a Graph with each `Edge` having some `weight`.

I have implemented dijkstra's Algorithm to find the shortest Path from `Vertex` A to B.

`Weights` for the Graph are read from a Key/Value DB. [`redis.io`].

- Each `Weights DB` is around 2 GBs.
- There are 50 DBs for `weights`. [Or 50 different files each  2 GB having weight values which I stored in the Redis.io].
- To find the shortest Path, `function FindPath(Start, End, DB_name)` is used.

Dijkstras reads the weight values from memory[Redio.io is an in-memory key value store]. But my RAM is only 6GBs. It is not possible to store 2GBs * 50 DBs into the memory at the same time.

The request for the Path can be Random and Concurrent.

What is the best way to store the Weights DB?

Is increasing the RAM only option to increase the speed of the program execution?

EDIT

Number of Edges: 4,62,505

Comment: How many nodes and edges do you have?

Comment: 462K edges should not require so much RAM if the number of nodes is << E. Dijkstra's algorithm has a worst case space complexity of O(N^2) ~ O(E) I think. http://igraph.wikidot.com/algorithm-space-time-complexity

Comment: If all the weights are present in the RAM,it would not require much RAM but if 2 concurrent requests comes in trying to access 2 different DBs, then it is slow. With 1 DB it takes about half a second. As i issue concurrent requests, it takes more time.

Comment: It seems you have to find strategy to order the request and choosing which Db to cache.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is concerned the main option is to increase ram. You cannot achieve similar perfomance with a nosql DB (eg. mongodb).  Another option would be to try to parallelize the algorithm on a multi core system.  But this is very tough as the final solution is global.

[EDIT] 
The fastest way to store the weights is a contiguous array of weights indexed by edge number. One array per DB. If all arrays cannot fit in your ram , you can design some basic caching mechanims ,  swaping DB from file to array (hoping not all db are accessed simultaneously).